# Is it possible move asp.net membership separation into different layer (move WCF service)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-membership

I want to have (have already) all basic functionality which comes out of the box with standard asp.net membership like: `ValidateUser`, `CreateUser`, `ChangePassword` etc..

But I want to separate it out to a different layer, I don't want the web application to have access directly to the database.

The question is should I try to use standard membership, or do I need implement everything from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this may be something you are looking for?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WSSecurityProvider.aspx

Hope it helps.